# Boyce-Codd normal form with circular functional dependencies

Tags: database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies, bcnf

In relational database design, For example, there is schema S(banker, bname, customer) and function dependencies (FDs)

banker->bname
customer,bname->banker

Is schema S in BCNF? Or it should be:
(banker, bname) and (customer, banker)

Comment: Is the FD, banker->bname  (customer,bname)->banker  ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 'S' is in BCNF. Here's Chris Date's informal definition of BCNF.

> A relvar is in BCNF if and only if the only determinants are candidate
>   keys. (*An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, p 367)

The term *determinant* means the left-hand side of a functional dependency. If there's a functional dependency whose left-hand side isn't a candidate key, then the relation isn't in BCNF.

Let's rewrite your example in traditional notation.

```
R{ABC}
A->B
BC->A
```

There are two candidate keys: AC and BC.  The left-hand side of A->B isn't a candidate key. So R isn't in BCNF.

> Or it should be: (banker, bname) and (customer, banker)

No. Your functional dependencies say quite clearly that customer does *not* determine banker.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be (banker, bname) and (customer, banker).  Looks more like a foreign key relationship to me.

Comment: I think so as well, so BCNF can break 1 FD into more tables, but not more than 1FD in 1 table, right?

Comment: Yes, FDs can indeed become inexpressible as a consequence of splitting relation schemas.  The phenomenon is called "dependency preservation".  In logical database design, the FD needs to be reinstated ("replaced") by a logical database constraint.